Is the entropy of a distribution that follows the exponential family differential equation always concave in the natural parameter?
Are there any proofs, conjectures, counterexamples, or other helpful references related to the titular question?
To clarify, let the entropy of a random variable $X$ distributed according to a parametric distribution $P(X|\theta)$ be
$$H(\theta) = -\mathbb{E}_{X|\theta}[\log P(X|\theta)]$$
I want to know whether $H(\theta)$ is concave in $\theta$ for a distribution that satisfies the differential equation
$$\frac{\partial P(x|\theta)}{\partial \theta} = \left ( T(x) - \mathbb{E}_{X|\theta}[T(X)] \right ) P(x|\theta)$$
Solutions to this differential equation include distributions from the exponential family, which all have log-likelihoods of the form
$$ \theta T(x) - A(\theta) + B(x)$$
but it would also include certain mixtures of these distributions. For example, a mixture of binomial distributions with the same value of $p$, but different $n$ would satisfy this differential equation.

Suppose $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure and that the set $E$ of $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\int_\mathcal{X} e^{\theta\cdot T(x)}\,\mu(dx)<\infty$$
has nonempty interior. Let $\{P_\theta:\theta\in E\}$ a family of probability measures of the form
$$P_\theta(dx)=p_\theta(x)\,\mu(dx)=e^{\theta\cdot T(x)-\xi(\theta)}\mu(dx)$$
It is not difficult to check that the map $\phi:\theta\mapsto \int_\mathcal{X} e^{\theta\cdot T(x)}\,\mu(dx)$ is analytic on $\operatorname{int}(E)$ and
$$ \phi^{(n)}=\int_{\mathcal{X}}T^n(x)p_\theta(x)\,\mu(dx)$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$.
In particular, the maps $\xi: \theta\mapsto\log\Big(\int_\mathcal{X} e^{\theta\cdot T(x)}\,\mu(dx)\Big)$ is smooth on $\operatorname{int}(E)$. Furthermore, by Hölder's inequality, $\xi(\theta)$ is convex on $\operatorname{int}(E)$.
Although not needed, observe that
$$0=\int_\mathcal{X} (T(x)-\xi'(\theta))p_\theta(x)\,\mu(dx)$$
and so, $E_\theta(T(X))=\xi'(\theta)$.
and
$$\xi''(\theta)=\int_\mathcal{X}T(x)(T(x)-\xi'(\theta))p_\theta(x)\,\mu(dx)=E_\theta[T^2(X)]-\big(E_\theta[T(X)]\big)^2=\operatorname{var}_\theta(T(X))>0
$$
Now, the entropy of $P_\theta$ as defined by the OP is
\begin{align}
H(\theta)&=-E_\theta[\log(p_\theta(X))]=-\int_\mathcal{X}\log(p_\theta(x))p_\theta(x)\,\mu(dx)\\
&=-\int_\mathcal{X}\theta\cdot T(x)\,p_\theta(x)\,\mu(dx)+\xi(\theta)\\
&=-\theta\cdot E_\theta[T(X)]+\xi(\theta)\\
&=-\theta\cdot \xi'(\theta)+\xi(\theta)
\end{align}
Notice that for any $x\in\mathcal{X}$ fixed, $p_\theta(x)$ is smooth in $\theta$. Notice that
$$\partial^2_{\theta,\theta}\log(p_\theta(x))=\frac{\partial^2_{\theta,\theta}p_\theta(x)}{p_\theta(x)}-\big(\partial_\theta \log(p_\theta(x))\big)^2$$
Taking expectations yields
$$H''(\theta)=-E_\theta\big[\partial^2_{\theta,\theta}\log(p_\theta(X))\big]=E_\theta\big[\big(\partial_\theta \log(p_\theta(X))\big)^2\big]\geq0
$$

In general, if $\{Q_\theta:\theta\in\Theta\}$ is a family of probability measures  dominated by a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ and

$q_\theta(x)=\frac{dP_\theta}{d\mu}(x)$ is twice differentiable in $\theta$,
$\partial_\theta \int_\mathcal{X} f_\theta(x)\,\mu(dx) =\int_\mathcal{X}\partial_\theta f_\theta(x)\,\mu(dx)$
with $f_\theta(\theta) = q_\theta(x))$ and $f_\theta(\theta) = \partial_\theta q_\theta(x))$,

then
$$\partial^2_{\theta,\theta}E_\theta[\log(q_\theta(X))]=_{\theta,\theta}E_\theta[\partial^2_{\theta,\theta}\log(q_\theta(X))]=-E_\theta[(\partial_\theta q_\theta(X)))^2]$$
This is a well known property if the Fisher information function.

Thanks for the answer! It's not entirely clear to me whether your arguments apply to every distribution that obeys the differential equation in the OP or just distributions from the exponential family. Or put another way, it is clear that the pdf in your post satisfies the differential equation, but it is not clear to me that it is the only form of distribution that satisfies the equation.

@nlupugla: Satisfying the differential equation you gave is irrelevant. As long as you as your distribution satisfies the conditions I quoted at the end of my posting (basically that differentiation of order 1 and 2 can be move inside the integral) then the entropy is a convex function (as a function of the parameter). That is basically the relation between the Fisher information and the hessian of the entropy.

Thanks for the clarification. A few more questions then. When you say the differential equation is irrelevant, are you basically saying it is neither a sufficient nor necessary condition for the entropy to be concave in the parameter? Second, the second part of your answer is a bit confusing, perhaps there are some typos? Did you mean to say $f = q = \partial_\theta q$? The condition $q = \partial_\theta q$ is very restrictive, only being satisfied if $q$ is an exponential function of $\theta$.

No I meant to say that one can move differentiation inside the integral when the integran is either $q_\theta$ or $\partial_\theta q_\theta$.

Then are you saying that all that's needed for the entropy to be concave in the parameter is for bringing the derivative inside the integral to be valid? It seems like this is not a tight enough constraint. By linearity of differentiation and integration, isn't this basically always true so long as the probability distribution isn't pathological in some sense (like discontinuous or non-differentiable in $\theta$?). How does your argument apply to say, a Bernoulli distribution with success probability $\cos^2 \theta$. The entropy oscillates with $\theta$, so it is not concave.

Or to put things a different way, your argument only seems to be valid in cases where the second derivative of the entropy equals the Fisher Information. This is certainly a sufficient condition (as the Fisher Information is non-negative), but there are many distributions where this equality does not hold, but the entropy is still concave in $\theta$. Consider a binomial distribution with fixed number of trials $n$ and success probability $p = \theta$. The Fisher info is just $n/(\theta (1-\theta))$, but the entropy, nor its second derivative have a nice closed form.

I do t know what you mean by tight condition etc.  Being able to exchange  first and second order differentiation is sufficient. In particular, the analytic it’s in the natural parameter of exponential type distributions allows for that to happen (they are rather special distributions) of course they are not the only ones for which this is possible. Notice that in your problem you are referring to the”natural” parameter of the exponential type distribution. $\cos^2\theta$ is not natural for Bernoulli.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
